# Netbeans created Jar does not work, but inside IDE program works

Tags: java, file, netbeans, jar

The Netbeans created Jar does not work, but inside the IDE program it works perfectly. 
I believe that the main class is set, so I'm not sure what the problem is, I think it might have something to do with the txt files I'm using, in the IDE they are in C:\Users\J\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PointOfSale\src\pointofsale (the text files are with my java files). After building the dist/ jar though the text files are inside the jar with no folders or anything (Jar is in C:\Users\J\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PointOfSale\dist). I this this might be the problem, if its helpful, I access the files using

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\pointofsale\\list.txt");
```

Comment: Define "Does not work".

Comment: When I press a button, nothing happens, I strongly suspect that it cant find my "menu.txt" file, as that is where the string thats supposed show up is from, as well as that, inside the Jar I checked the menu file and even when I manually place a value in there, it doesnt load the values from the txt file to the program on launch of app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Class.getResourceAsStream()` to load the file. It searches from inside the classpath (and therefore from inside the jar). Now you can't load the list.txt because it doesn't exist in the directory you're specifying, it's inside your jar.

Something along the lines of

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("list.txt"); // Or "/list.txt"
```

Will give you an InputStream you can use to load the file contents.

Comment: thanks, I cant really seem to get it working, will continue to try though. I think that File() expects a URI and im giving it a FileStream

Comment: Do you need the File for something? I thought you wanted to just read the contents.

Comment: I read from all of them, and write to all of them at different times. Using scanners and printwriters etc

Comment: So you don't need the File object then. Reading is handled with streams just fine, but of course you can't write to a file inside a jar.

Comment: I didnt know that you cant write to a file inside a jar, can you please help me with placing my files in the right places so that I can read and write

Comment: I used, File filex = new File(this.getClass().getResource("list.txt").getFile());, once again it worked in the IDE but not the jar

Comment: You can't keep the files inside the jar if you intend to write to them.

Comment: I've managed to get it working, I made the files external to the jar, thanks